# Calculate the sum of capacity per category in a pivot table linked to 3 different tables-Excel

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerpivot

Hallo I'm new with DAX expressions and I'm getting trouble when i want to calculate a value depending on different categories in each registry of my DB and show the report in a pivot table.

I have 3 tables: **Projects**, **Rates** and **Workers per Project**.
I want to calculate the required capacity per worker depending in which role are, in which type of project are and in which stage(phase) of the project are.
With SUMX(Rates;Rates[Req. Capacity]) I'm getting the same value for all the workers in each role.

```
   [Workers per Project][1]
   [Projects][2]
   [Rates ][3]
```

This is the result im looking for:
[Result wanted][4]

can someone help me to make it work ?
Thanks in advance ! :)

```
    [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtGgT.png
    [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QObD.png
    [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8RDH.png
    [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKMrS.png
```

Comment: Something's wrong with your pictures.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
--Measure on Rates table
--Change semicolon for comma if needed
--Made in Excel because it was already running :)
Required Capacity :=
VAR RolesByCW = VALUES(WorkersPerProject[Role]) --CW(CurrentWorker)
VAR ProjectsIDByCW = DISTINCT(WorkersPerProject[Project]) 
VAR ProjectTypeByCWandProjectID=
CALCULATETABLE(VALUES(Projects[Type]);CONTAINSROW(ProjectsIDByCW;Projects[Project]))
RETURN
CALCULATE(
SUM(Rates[Req. Capacity]);
CONTAINSROW(RolesByCW;Rates[Role]);
CONTAINSROW( ProjectTypeByCWandProjectID;Rates[Type])
)
```

Comment: No problem. Just checking for some questions about it. It looks everything is fine so far. Cheers